# Asynchronous send mail while action return content

Tags: email, asp.net-mvc-2, asynchronous

In my web portal while somebody commented on a user's post i send email to post owner about it.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SubmitComment(...)
{
    Comment comment = new Comment {...
    Mail.SendEmail(...);
    return Content("OK");
}
```

When a comment submitted a post
request with ajax and append the
comment bottom of comment div. Because
of sending email take relatively
longer time response return late. So
users begin to click submit link more
than once. How can I return content
while send email at background. Async
Controller is a choice but the only
where i need is this section.

Any recommendation, tutorial etc.

Comment: What are you using to send the mail? If you use the IIS's virtual SMTP server the mail is queued locally to be sent later. the configuration depends on the version of IIS but is extremely simple.

Comment: amit_g I am using gmail smtp to send email.

Comment: Do you have control over IIS? If so, search for IIS Virtual SMTP and configure it. You would setup the IIS to send email using the GMail. So your application would queue the email on IIS's SMTP server and that happens instantly. The IIS would later keep sending the emails.

Comment: yes i have control over IIS. how can I configure it?

Comment: http://www.jppinto.com/2010/07/how-to-configure-iis-smtp-server-to-forward-emails-using-a-gmail-account/

Answer (score 0):

check this link, it describes how to send email async and catch message about sending status

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx#Y2052

and after in controller i would create an action
that will be looking into session where you write data about sending email for particular user...

and of course reading it using ajax for response... the problem is the time may wary, so the question is .. is it the best way?
p